# Magento Custom Block Methods Not Working

Tags: module, magento-1, blocks

I've created a custom module in Magento but the methods I have defined for my block are not working for some reason. I can create an instance of the block in a template and call the parent blocks methods but not the methods I have defined.

/app/code/local/MyCompany/Morecategories/Block/List.php

```
<?php
class MyCompany_Morecategories_Block_List extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{

  public function getMoreCategories() {
    return 'More categories';
  }
}
```

Then in my template file, if I run `$this->getMoreCategories()` it returns null.

I've tried running `get_class($this)`, and it returns `MyCompany_Morecategories_Block_List`.

I've also run `get_class_methods($this)` but it only returned the parent blocks methods.

I can't imagine why my methods are not working.

**Edit:**  Here is my `config.xml` file for the module:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <MyCompany_Morecategories>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
    </MyCompany_Morecategories>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <blocks>
      <morecategories>
        <class>MyCompany_Morecategories_Block</class>
      </morecategories>
    </blocks>
  </global>
</config>
```

**Edit 2:** Here is the custom layout update xml code I have for the category

```
<reference name="content">
  <block type="morecategories/list" name="morecategories_list"   template="mycompany/catalog/category/more.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

Comment: Do you have APC, or similar, running that might have cached an old version of this class? Or are you using Magento's compilation mode which has an old version of the file in the compiled state?

Comment: Both the cache and compiler are disabled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you update your layout xml block type? Does it work if you try:

```
<block type="morecategories/list" name="morecategories_list" template="PATH TO YOUR TEMPLATE"/>
```

Comment: This is how I referenced the block. I'm inserting this block through the custom layout update in the admin for a category.

Comment: Can you post more of your code? And ill try my best to help you.

Comment: I have edited my question to include the config.xml file. Anything else you need?

Comment: Can you share what xml code you are using to update the layout in the admin panel? And where are you hoping to output this data?

Comment: Question updated with custom layout update xml

Comment: I just tested your code and it works. Are you sure you have the right settings in your MyCompany_Morecategories.xml file?      <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <MyCompany_Morecategories>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </MyCompany_Morecategories>
    </modules>
</config>